# FTP File upload Exception 'Software caused connection abort: recv failed' -JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to upload multiple directories to FTP but after 4-5 minutes of uploading stared I am getting  **'Software caused connection abort: recv failed'** exception only a few files got uploaded. I checked the FTP Time out settings it is set to 10 minutes and also tried both enterLocalPassiveMode() and sendNoOp() but didn't work please help me to fix this.

```
public class FTPUpload {


    public  void initFtpupload(String localparentDir,String batchno) //not in use
    {
         try {
            readProperty();
            CreateFile();
            localDirPath=localparentDir;
            lotno=batchno;
            FTPUpload ftpobj = new FTPUpload(ftpIp, ftpPort, ftpUname, ftpPassword);
            System.out.println("Local Dir PAth:"+localparentDir);
            System.out.println("Local dir path: "+localDirPath);
            ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpRootDir);
             if(true)
             {
                 IterateDirectory(localDirPath);
             }
            ftpobj.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
             String error=stackTraceToString(e);
            genLog("Exception in InitFtpUpload: "+e);
            System.out.println("Exception:" + e);
            genLog("Exception Trace:" + error);
        }
    }

    // Constructor to connect to the FTP Server
    public FTPUpload(String host, int port, String username, String password) throws Exception {

        java.util.Date dtCurDate = new java.util.Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss");
        String strCurDate = sdfDate.format(dtCurDate);
        String strLogPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "Log";
        String strLogFilePath = strLogPath + File.separator + "FTPConnectionLog_" + strCurDate + ".log";
        File logfile=new File(strLogFilePath);

        ftp = new FTPClient();
        //ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
        ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(logfile)));
        int reply;
        ftp.connect(host, port);
        System.out.println("FTP URL is:" + ftp.getDefaultPort());
        reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            ftp.disconnect();
            genLog("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
            throw new Exception("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
        }
        ftp.login(username, password);
        ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        genLog("Connected");
        System.out.println("Connected ");

    }

    // list the files in a specified directory on the FTP
    public static boolean IterateDirectory(String localRootDirectoryPath) throws IOException {
        // lists files and directories in the current working directory
         //for test
        ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpRootDir);
        System.out.println("Inside IterateDirectory ");
            FTPFile dirs[]=ftp.listFiles();
            for(FTPFile f:dirs)
            {
                System.out.println("####"+f);
            }
            //upto this...
        boolean verificationFilename = false;
        String newFtpDirectoy = "";
        File localfile = new File(localRootDirectoryPath);
        File files[] = localfile.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            String details = file.getName();
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                IterateDirectory(file.getPath());
                iflag=false;
            } else {
                if (iflag == false) {
                    localRootDirectoryPath = file.getParent();
                    newFtpDirectoy = localRootDirectoryPath.substring(localRootDirectoryPath.indexOf("HUB"));
                    newFtpDirectoy = newFtpDirectoy.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
                    if (true) {
                            makeDirectories(ftp, newFtpDirectoy);
                        String localParenDir = file.getParent();
                        genLog("ftpDirPath: "+ftpDirPath);
                        genLog("New FTP Dir: "+newFtpDirectoy);
                        genLog("Local parent dir: "+localParenDir);
                         System.out.println("ftpDirPath: "+ftpDirPath);
                        System.out.println("New FTP Dir: "+newFtpDirectoy);
                        System.out.println("Local parent dir: "+localParenDir);
                        uploadDirectory(ftp, ftpDirPath, localParenDir, newFtpDirectoy);
                        mailist.add(localRootDirectoryPath);
                        File f=new File(localRootDirectoryPath);
                        String finalPath=f.getParent();
                        if(!mailistlocal.contains(finalPath)){
                            mailistlocal.add(finalPath);
                        }
                    }
                    iflag = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Disconnect the connection to FTP

    public void disconnect() {
        if (this.ftp.isConnected()) {
            try {
                this.ftp.logout();
                this.ftp.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException f) {
                // do nothing as file is already saved to server
            }
            System.out.println("FTP Disconnected successfully");
            genLog("FTP Disconnected successfully");
        }
    }


            }
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: You might consider using SFTP. Have a look in here, http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using an existing library rather than creating your own.  For example: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-1.4.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

EDIT (Added working example):

This code worked for me using the jar file found here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.commons.net.tftp.TFTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.tftp.TFTPClient;

public class FtpExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String fileName = "C:\\TEMP\\MyTestFile.txt";
        String hostName = "speedtest.tele2.net";
        String remoteFileName = "upload/MyTestFile.txt";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        System.out.println("Sending file: " + file.getName() + "(exists: " + file.exists() + ")");
        sendFile(file, hostName, remoteFileName);
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }

    private static void sendFile(File file, String hostName, String remoteFileName) {
        TFTPClient tftp = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            tftp = new TFTPClient();
            tftp.open();
            tftp.sendFile(remoteFileName, TFTP.BINARY_MODE, inputStream, hostName);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exp);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (tftp != null) {
                    tftp.close();
                }
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception exp) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(exp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That's the library which I'm Using (org.apache.commons.net.ftp)@John

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error

```
Software caused connection abort
```

From a FTP client perspective, the server was closing my connection after successful authentication, because my ip was no whitelisted in the ftp server cloud provider.

After whitelisting my public IP, I could connect to FTP server succesfully.